# How to avoid slow queries when mixing ANY and ORDER + LIMIT?

Tags: postgresql

I have a [query](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/cbd7bbeebb058c8f#plan) with an `ORDER BY x LIMIT 20` that is slow because of an `articles.status = ANY ('{draft,suspended}'::text[])`.

I know I can make it faster by switching to a `UNION ALL` where I merge request with `status = draft` and `status = suspended`. But the issue will happen again on any ANY or IN parameters added to the query.

I am wondering how could I prevent this to happen and why PostgreSQL is not able to handle it by itself?

Often I have 2-3 `ANY` or `IN` on my queries, and I always need paginated and ordered result (page of 20 rows).

Comment: "But the issue will happen again on any ANY..."  So why not solve it again on any ANY?  You know how to.

Comment: @jjanes I can fix it but as I mention we will have new `ANY / IN` queries. Because of ORM. Queries are dynamic. End user can add filters. If I have a sum of 50 query params, I do not understand why I need to "trick" the planner to do the job properly by rewriting queries.

Comment: @jjanes It cannot be transformed automatically because it is not semantically equivalent. `UNION ALL` would be wrong of two of the array elements are identical. And `UNION` would be wrong if there were legitimate duplicate result rows. But you are right: the first case can be solved, it is just that nobody did it.

Comment: You can use a 80-20 rule approach. Log your users' queries for a long period (say 1 or 2 days). Then analyze which columns are most used (select the top 2 or 3), and create the appropriate indexes on those columns. That should help with performance for your most popular queries.